# How to connect to virt-viewer (remote viewer) from remote client

Tags: fedora, remote-desktop

I just installed a remote viewer `virt-viewer` on a Fedora based server

```
dnf install virt-viewer
```

but the command used to connect to the viewer from a remote client is

```
spice://(server name or IP address):(port)
```

and I do not know what `port` to use.

Must I forward a port? Is there a default port?

Thanks

**edit**

Is VNC preferable to virt-viewer?

Comment: Can you share what is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a remote view running by installing tiger VNC

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/infrastructure-services/TigerVNC/#

and I installed to my mac vnc remote viewer

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/macos/

and followed the instructions